# Loading Html Datatable through Perl

Tags: javascript, html, perl

I was wondering if there is a way that my index.html can call a perl handler to load a datatable within the index.html. No JQuery, but I can use Javascript. How would /should I go about this? As of now I'm just printing some html in the perl handler, but I really don't like doing that if I don't have to. So basically, is there a way I can get data from a perl cgi handler and take that data and load it into a html datatable. Thanks for tips / advice.

What I'm doing now is just calling the handler using :

```
    <form action="http://myExampleHandler.pl.cgi" method="get">

       <input type="submit" value="GO" />
    </form>
```

Perl:

```
 $dtd =
        "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\"
    \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd";

 print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";

 print( start_html( { dtd => $dtd,
                 title => "Database mySQL example" } ) );
 print "Ok let\'s start...<p>";

 $dbh = DBI->connect('dbi:mysql:MyDbName','MyUserName','MyPassword')
or die "Connection Error: $DBI::errstr\n";
$sql = "select * from Animal";
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute
or die "SQL Error: $DBI::errstr\n";

#@data = $sth->fetchrow_array();

#print header;
#print "Content-Type: text/html\n\n";

print "<table width=\"900\"> \n";

print "<tr><td></td><td>Name</td><td>Type</td><td></td></tr>\n";

my($animalId, $animalName, $animalType);

while (@row = $sth->fetchrow_array) {
    $animalId = $row[0];
    $animalName = $row[1];
    $animalType = $row[3];

    print "<tr><td></td><td>$animalName</td><td>$animalType</td><td></td></tr>\n";
}

print "</table>\n";

print( end_html() );
```

I guess my preferred way would be to a javascript call this handler and have the handler pass back all the rows in a array or json. Then it's easy, I would just have to load the datatable with the data.

Answer (score 0):

Of course.  jQuery is written in javascript, so anything done by jQuery can be done in javascript.  You need to send an XMLHttpRequest (or as it's more popularly known: an AJAX request) to your perl program.  Your perl program can then send back any string as a response.  Your js code can read that string, and then insert it (or anything else) into your html table--all without reloading a new page.

Comment: Any way you could show an example of using this? I have used jquery ajax before, but not the javascript way, if it's different. And can I continue to use "print" in the perl? or do is there a certain way to send back data to the index.html?

Comment: The trick is to make it cross browser, which means you have to do a lot of different checks.  Here is one tutorial (of thousands): http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/news/how-to-make-ajax-requests-with-raw-javascript/.  Your perl script will have no idea who wrote the javascript program that sent the request: you are the jQuery programmers.

Comment: Note how the whole function in that tutorial reduces to one line of code in jQuery (the jQuery line is included at the end)

Comment: Would this be a better approach than just printing the html in the perl script itself?

Comment: It's hard to say.  It's really a matter of aesthetics.  For instance, have you seen those html pages where a stock price in the text updates in real time?  As you are reading the article, the stock price changes constantly.  If the page reloaded every time the stock price changed, it would be really annoying.  However, if you only want to update the page once, and do the update in response to a user's action, then the flicker of the page reloading serves as a signal that something changed on the page, and because the flicker of the page reloading only happens once, it isn't super annoying.